# shared_ptr<T> to const shared_ptr<const T>&

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion, pass-by-const-reference, reference-binding

I feel confused about shared_ptr, and my main question is: **does c++ create a new object (shared_ptr object) when I do the following?**

```
void Func1(const shared_ptr<T>& rhs) {}
void Func2(const shared_ptr<const T>& rhs) {}
shared_ptr<T> v1;
Func1(v1);
Func2(v1);
```

Clearly, `Func1(v1)` is passed by ref. However, **how about `Func2(v1)` ?**

Will the complier does the following thing behind?

```
shared_ptr<const T> tmp_v2 = v1;
Func2(tmp_v2);
```

**I care about it, because `Func2` may cost more time (if it does create a new shared_ptr object) than `Func1`.**

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything magical here, it's just one of the [`shared_ptr` constructor overload (number 9)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r );
```

> 9) Constructs a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership of the object managed by r. If r manages no object, *this manages no object too. The template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if Y* is not implicitly convertible to (until C++17)compatible with (since C++17) T*.

In order for that to work, `const T` has to be implicitly convertible from `T`, another object **will not be created**, only be managed by another `shared_ptr`.

Comment: "_const T has to be implicitly convertible from T_" what do you mean?

Comment: @curiousguy I think he means exactly what he said. The constructor requires that `Y` is implicitly convertible to `T`. In the OP's case `Y` is `T` and `T` is `const T`, so it requires that "T is implicitly convertible to const T" or in other words, "const T has to be implicitly convertible from T". Like he said. Luckily, const T is always convertible from T, so it works.